# How do I filter nested List of Map items from dynamoDB in python dynamically

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How do I filter nested List of Map items from dynamoDB in python dynamically.

Below is the Json document.

```
"Items": [
{
  "shows": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ],
  "area": [
    {
      "areaCode": "ID1",
      "street": [
        "pvr1"
      ]
    }
  ],
 }
]
```

How do I filter records based on 'areaCode' = "ID1"
I am getting records when I specify the index, but cannot hardcode the index value since the list might have more items. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

```
response = table.scan(
     FilterExpression = Attr("area[0].areaCode").contains("ID1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not have the ability to do wildcard searches on complex attributes like you are describing.  If you want to search or filter by the area code attribute, you'll need to move it into an attribute or incorporate it in your primary key.

The search functionality provided by DDB over complex attributes is limited.