# DynamoDB Query by by nested array

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a Companies table in DynamoDB that looks like this:

```
company: {
  id: "11",
  name: "test",
  jobs: [
    {
      "name": "painter",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "gardner"
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to make a scan query that get all the companies with the "painter" job inside their jobs array

I am using python and boto3

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
jobs = ["painter"]
response = self.table.scan(
            FilterExpression=Attr('jobs.name').is_in(jobs)
        )
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use array indexing in a document path e.g. `jobs[0].name` but there's no way to specify the equivalent of `jobs[*].name`. Note: the phrase "scan query" is going to confuse people, so best not to write that. Both "scan" and "query" are very specific things in DynamoDB. You're using a "scan", not a "scan query".

Comment: reading the docs carefully you will see the filtering happens AFTER scan or query, but before results are returned to the user. In that sense, you can just retrieve the results and do the filtering on our your outside of the table.scan https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression    "A filter expression is applied after a Scan finishes but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Scan consumes the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may not be doable [in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222698/how-do-i-filter-nested-list-of-map-items-from-dynamodb-in-python-dynamically), however it's possible that the method applied in that link may still be useful. If you know the maximum length of the jobs array over all of your data, you could create an expression for each index chained with ORs. Notably I could not find documentation for handling map and list scan expressions, so I can't really say whether you'd also need to check that you're not going out of bounds.